# Positioning selectors with correct dimensions that scale on different screen sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, jquery-selectors

Trying to build a page layout using html and css, the page contains jQuery UI selector elements

- Looking to have

  ```
  <div id="content">
      <img id="grid" src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
  </div>
  ```

placed in the center of the screen, equal distance from left, right, top and bottom window edges.

- And a left hand menu, containing 8 images, 4x2 rowsxcols layout

  ```
  <div id="menu" style="width:150px;float:left;">
      <b>Stock images</b><br>
          <ol id="selectable">
              <li id="house.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="gherkin.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="water.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="tree.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="me.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="hey.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="wutang.jpg" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
              <li id="test.png" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x40"/></li>
      </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="float:left;">
      <img id="grid" src="http://placehold.it/350x250"/>
  </div>
  ```

For some reason I cannot adjust the height dimensions of `#selectable` and `#selectalbe li` elements.
Selectable elements should not be obstructed by `grid` element.
Aim is to use percentages when possible instead of hardcoded values so page will render correctly on different sized devices.
The header and footer divs position fine.
Appreciate any help with this!

Heres a jsfiddle of the current layout ..
http://jsfiddle.net/TdNXD/10/
Targetted layout, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5eLg.png)

Comment: You've gone `float` happy. `float` is for text flow.

Comment: Removed `float:left;` from `<div id="content">`, this is what i had in jsfiddle .. withhout `float` in `div id="menu"` `content` is appended to the selectors

Comment: Alright, there's some interpretation in this as I wasn't real sure I know how you wanted it laid out, but take a look at this and let me know what you think: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TdNXD/7/ It displays perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE8-9. IE7 was the only one that was a problem, since it doesn't support `display: table*`.

Comment: this is not what im looking for, i need the jQuery `selectors` to have a 4x2 layout down the left hand side (need to be scaled down for this) and the `grid` to be centered in the screen.

Comment: What jQuery selectors are you referring to? The `:radio` buttons that were along the top, in a `div` with a `#header`? And what you want in the center is the `#grid`, or the gray box? Where does that go? I more or less kept in place what was where. It can be swapped around (and the CSS is a bit tighter regardless). See it in fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TdNXD/7/embedded/result/ Also, I put the colors on the background so I could keep track of the elements visually. Especially when you use `float`s, you *have* to keep track of the flow of those and surrounding elements.

Comment: I'm referring to the list items under `<ol id="selectable">` which show small images, it seems they are not scaling in your solution they appear the same dimensions whether viewed full screen or not .. would also like them to appear in 4x2 grid layout

Comment: Can you provide a mockup/drawing of what the layout is intended to look like? That would probably help. If I took screenshots of what you had and what I did, other than the color they wouldn't look too different. I did put constraints on the `#wrapper` to, due to the small jsFiddle result window size. I mostly straightened up the CSS and markup, so it's not necessarily a solution or I would have posted it as an answer. Do you have a mockup tool? If not, checkout http://pencil.evolus.vn/. It's free *and* frickin awesome. Do a layout mockup, export to PNG and upload it to imgur.

Comment: evoluspencil is a great tool, thanks for tip! [Heres](http://i.imgur.com/y8Bly.png) a link to the proposed layout

Comment: Oh come on, that's not that different. Pencil is pretty good, too. I might donate to that one.

Comment: Its similiar but not quite there, the CSS on `#selectable` and `#selectable li` do not scale causing them to display in wrong dimensions, and too large

Comment: That's easy stuff to adjust. Have you heard of Bootstrap? http://bootswatch.com/ It's a grid-based layout system (from Twitter) that has some pretty cool features and nice looking stuff. That last link has free templates, if you're interested. There's others like 960.gs and Masonry out there as well.

Comment: yeah ive heard of bootstrap but think it would be better to just implement this layout without additional libraries

Comment: @JaredFarrish updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdNXD/10/), now closer to goal .. how to scale down the `#selectable` and `#selectable li` elements height is the problem now

Comment: I've got it almost worked out, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Here's where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TdNXD/12/embedded/result/ For some reason I haven't figured out yet, the `header` is making something overflow. So there's that. And I haven't even touched the placement of the middle image. Almost there.

Comment: Alright, try this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/16/show/light/ It works awesome in every browser. But. IE7 and 8. IE7, whatever, but IE8 is still cutting it a little close...

Comment: And sans the colorful treatment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/17/show/light/

Comment: this looks great, cheers! if you could get the placement of the middle image in the center id appreciate it, post it as an answer for acceptance :)

Comment: @bobbyme01 - Well, that all depends on how you interpret "middle". It is, technically, exactly in the middle of the block to the right of the aside with the stock images, which itself is `240px` wide. So, if I put a `border-right: 240px solid #faa` (the color being so you can see it) on the `#main` "cell", and in effect "center" that block left *and* right, you get http://fiddle.jshell.net/TdNXD/18/show/light/. So the question is, what should it be centered to?

Comment: Actually, it should be `260px`: http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/19/show/light/

Comment: It's easier to see the width comparison in color: http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/20/show/light/ If you resize the screen, the left `ol`'s padding gets resized, so at smaller widths, the left cell is going to be narrower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was really more of an overhaul than a tweak, it would be a very long answer showing all of the changes that I've made to make it work. In that, refer to the result:

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/16/show/light/

And the editable fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/16/

And in gray tones:

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/17/show/light/
>
> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/17/

Now, as your comment indicates, you're trying to center the `img` in the middle of the right content area. In the above fiddles, it is in the middle... of that content area (a `div#main` I added). So if we take into account the width of the `nav` on the left of `#main`, you get:

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/19/show/light/
>
> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/19/

Which in color is easier to see centering of the `img` if it's all in color:

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/20/show/light/
>
> http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/TdNXD/20/

The above does include a slight issue I noticed, in that when the window is resized, the `poadding` on the `#menu` narrows, which means the absolute width of the right `border` then becomes slightly wider than the left `#main`. It's probably not or barely noticeable (as in, maybe `6-10px`), but I thought I'd mention it.

Other things to consider:

- **The layout breaks in IE7 and 8.** It's worse in IE7, but in IE8 it's still pretty horrid. My thought is IE's lack of support for `display: table`, `min-width`, and some special selectors like `input[type]` (etc.) are the root cause, but I have not confirmed which need to be handled. If you have to support these versions, I would suggest using an IE conditional stylesheet to "fix" IE7/8's display, which will either involve using `float` techniques (not recommended, but doable) or (*shudder*`) replacing the semantic markup with actual` table` elements.
- You really need to go through the markup and stylesheet, and most of all take a look at some of the decisions I incorporated into the design. I modified the markup to be more semantic, so you'll see HTML5 elements like `section`, `aside`, `article`, and `nav` in place of what was there before. I also wrapped some of the content in `p` tags if I thought it appropriate. One thing I'm thinking now is that the `Stock Images` text should probably be in a `h2` block, too, since that's not technically not paragraph text. Same goes for `Input URL` and `Grid Dimensions`, although those would probably fit as `fieldset` and `legend` candidates due to the functionality.
- Note as well I removed from my fiddle the parts that weren't in use, like the `#feedback` styles).
- I also gave a `min-width` to several elements, including the `#container`. This was driven by the desire to maintain layout integrity in the "Input URL" and "Grid dimensions" `input`s. If you want it to be truly responsive and maintain layout integrity from wide to narrow, you need to reflow those at certain widths with size-specific properties.

Well, it was still a long answer, but hopefully that helps. Let me know if you have any questions.