# How do I get divs to act like they're floating around a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu div that I want to stay fixed on the left while the rest of the content that scrolls floats to the right of it. I have the menu at 20% width, a top box that's 80% w and  boxes below the top box that are 20% w so it should all line up to fill the screen, the only thing is that the divs are floating behind the fixed element instead of beside it, what's the best way to fix this?

Here's the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8y2t2/14/.

The "maintop" div should fill the remaining 80% width of the screen instead of floating behind the "leftnav" div and having the "portolfio" boxes floating beside it. I feel like there's some simple solution for this I'm missing? Any ideas?

```
* { margin: 0; }
html, body { height:100%; } 
body {margin:0px;background-color:#fff;}
#leftnav {background-color:#232323;width:20%;min-height: 100%;height:auto!important;float:left;text-align:center;position:fixed;left:0;}
#portfolio {white-space: nowrap;text-align:center;margin:0;}
#portfolio ul {margin:0;padding:0;}
#portfolio li {width: 20%;display:inline-block;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle; margin:0;padding:0;float:left;}
#portfolio img {max-width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
#maintop {width:80%;height:45%;background-color:#caab7e;float:left;text-align:center;}

<body>
<div id="leftnav"></div>
<div id="maintop"></div>
<div id="portfolio">
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/000/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/090/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/900/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/009/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/000/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/090/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/900/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/009/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/000/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/090/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/900/fff"></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x300/009/fff"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: In my (somewhat opinionated) opinion, you've got something along the lines going on that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064082/positioning-selectors-with-correct-dimensions-that-scale-on-different-screen-siz/14087563#14087563) had. Ultimately, your markup and CSS needs a refactor and a good stiff talking-to; you need to *take a step back* and *think* about what you're doing *from a grid POV*. I see all the time people who, for various reasons, get caught up in what they've managed to produce and fail to recognize a rethink and a step above looking down is needed. Rethink, restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following css for `#maintop` and `#portfolio`.  This works because your absolute positioning removes the `#leftnav` from the document flow.  Even though `#leftnav` is sized for 20%, it acts as if it is on a separate layer which was causing your other two divs to calculate their position relative to the document body.

```
#maintop {
    width:80%;
    height:45%;
    background-color:#caab7e;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}

#portfolio {
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    width:80%;
    margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8y2t2/20/

Comment: that fixes that div but that still doesn't solve the fact that the portfolio lis will still be floating behind the fixed leftnav div

Comment: @BlakeBowman - Also, don't forget that jsFiddle defaults to include Normalize.css, which is active in your fiddles. It doesn't appear to make any perceptual difference toggled on or off, but I figured I'd point that out (I forget all the time).